# android error while compiling com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0

Tags: java, android

Currently, my android `compileSdkVersion` is set to 24 and in my dependencies, I have included `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'`

However when I try to build, I get an error of:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet while using this?

Comment: @VinayJaju yup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is a compatibility issue in your dependencies. Your support library is not compatible with the other library, something like Firebase/Google Play Service.

Comment: How would you recommend updating Firebase/Google play Service from your dependencies. I currently have `compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0') {
        force = true;
    }`

Comment: Congratulations!