# Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zza;

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-2.0

I have this error:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zza;

I am not getting how to solve this, please help.

[image: !!]

I don't know whether to include some lib or what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems of `Multiple dex files define` usually arise when you have duplicate dependency entry in your app `build.gradle`. In this case, you have a duplicate Firebase dependencies.

You need to use the same version either `9.0.2` or `9.6.1`:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
```

or

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
```

***Please be aware*** that if you use some support library version like `24.0.0` there is a chance for compatibility issue with firebase. You need to use the latest of support library or find the compatible firebase version. Read more at [android error while compiling com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575410/android-error-while-compiling-com-android-supportsupport-v424-0-0)

Answer (score 2):

> you need to use same version of `firebase` `dependencies`

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
```

**or**

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
```