# error in build gradle module android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

I have an error in the following code:

```
{
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
```

Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gkOM.png
The error is:

> Gradle 2.2.0 is using

What could be the problem?

Error log:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:Avasarangal:generateDebugSources, :Avasarangal:mockableAndroidJar, :Avasarangal:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :Avasarangal:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
E:\MY ANDROID SOURSE CODE\railway\orginal\Avasarangal\src\main\res\menu\menu_search.xml
Error:(7, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha').
E:\MY ANDROID SOURSE CODE\railway\orginal\Avasarangal\src\main\res\menu\search.xml
Error:(7, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha').
E:\MY ANDROID SOURSE CODE\railway\orginal\Avasarangal\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\menu\menu_search.xml
Error:(7, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha').
E:\MY ANDROID SOURSE CODE\railway\orginal\Avasarangal\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\menu\search.xml
Error:(7, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha').
Error:Execution failed for task ':Avasarangal:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 59.967 secs
Information:5 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: kindly post the complete error message

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your `compileSdkVersion`, `BuildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `support library` to use the more recent version. You can try using version 26. You should not use Google Play Service version >= 9.0 with support library <= 24 because there is compatibility issue (more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616652/4758255)

```
android {

  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion 26.0.2

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:E:/MY ANDROID SOURSE CODE/biju&#39;s app/gkpsc/orginal/Avasarangal/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:E:/MY ANDROID SOURSE CODE/biju&#39;s app/gkpsc/orginal/Avasarangal/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: You need to add the google maven. Please read my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0/45876864#45876864

Comment: allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}                                                                                                       
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

this problem will appear when try to **compile** lib version that not compatible with the **compileSdkVersion** ,your problem will solve if you add the google repository .

open bulid.gradle in main project folder and add the following code
 in allprojects {

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

I try to using this and solve my problem